# Counting specific characters in a table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Specific characters (say "c") in a dataset can be counted using

`SUM(LEN(A1:C4)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1:C4, "c",)))/LEN("c")`.

Using this formula, the number of "c"s in the following dataset is 3.

**My question is how do I "filter" the results of the above formula so that I can count the number of "c"s for just rows named BOB?**

My `database` is large so this is a simplified example.  The answer for the example below would be 2 (2 "c"s associated with BOB).

[EXAMPLE DATASET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFnhT.png)

I tried embeding the FILTER function in the formula and then tried embeding the SUMIF function. I was unsuccessful getting results in either case.

Comment: Assuming MS365 `=ROWS(TEXTSPLIT(CONCAT(FILTER(A1:C4,A1:A4="BOB")),,"c"))-1`

Answer (score 0):

### Count String Occurrences in Filtered Data

```
=LET(data,A2:C11,filter_col,1,filter_string,"Bob",count_string,"c",
   f,FILTER(data,INDEX(data,,filter_col)=filter_string,""),
IFERROR(SUM(LEN(f)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(f,count_string,"")))/LEN(count_string),))
```

[image]

```
=LET(data,$A2:$C11,filter_col,F2,filter_string,F3,count_string,F4,
   f,FILTER(data,INDEX(data,,filter_col)=filter_string,""),
IFERROR(SUM(LEN(f)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(f,count_string,"")))/LEN(count_string),))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=LET(
    data, A1:C10,
    names, TAKE(data, , 1),
    fname, "BOB",
    fin, SUM(MAP(FILTER(data, names = fname), LAMBDA(m, SUM(N(MID(m, SEQUENCE(LEN(m)), 1) = "c"))))),
    fin
)
```

[image]